# How do I store an embed when sending an embed?

Tags: discord.js

I have a simple code to send an embed, which works just fine, it's just that at some point I want to be able to directly delete that embed that was just sent. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least to the library, [sending](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) an embed is just like sending a normal message but with an embed as an addition. If you use code that looks something like this to send your message:

```
myChannel.send("My Message", myEmbed);
```

You can store the message ID for later use, such as to [delete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=delete) the message directly via a `MessageManager` (no need to fetch the message first or store the entire message object):

```
myChannel.send(
    "My Message", myEmbed
).then(message => {
    console.log(message.id); // Store this however you wish
    storedMessageId = message.id; // For example
});

// Elsewhere as needed
myChannel.messages.delete(storedMessageId);
```

You can also delete the sent message [after a delay](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete), like so:

```
myChannel.send(
    "My Message", myEmbed
).then(message => {
    message.delete({
        "timeout": 5000 // Delete 5s after sending
    });
});
```